# Is there an official source for the properties of stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, armor-class, damage-resistance, objects

The issue comes up mainly in relation to the spell *wall of stone*, which states that:

> A nonmagical wall of solid stone springs into existence at a point you
>   choose within range. [...] The wall is an object made of stone that
>   can be damaged and thus breached. (PHB 287)

The wall is a nonmagical object from the moment it is created. This, to me, reinforces that it is ordinary stone, with all the properties of it. However, the spell unhelpfully neglects to inform us of many of its properties, in particular any damage threshold, resistances and immunities.

> Objects are immune to poison and psychic damage. You might decide that
>   some damage types are more effective against a particular object or
>   substance than others. [...] Big objects such as castle walls often
>   have extra resilience represented by a damage threshold. (DMG 247)

While we can make up our own ruling, I am interested whether we got any official information that can be applied here.

**Is there any officially published material that describes the properties of stone, especially a wall and its resistances, immunities and damage threshold?** If yes, what does it say? Bonus points if that wall was created by the spell *wall of stone*.

Answer (score 4):

#### Stats for stone are not collated anywhere, but you can piece some useful things together...

1. **Stone is mentioned explicitly a few times in the [DMG
   section on objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#Objects)**:

In contrast to the spell description, which says the created wall will have an AC of 15, **the AC for stone is given as 17**. This disrepency could possibly be explained away by size -larger targets are considered to be easier to hit and so normally have lower AC, and the wall the the spell creates is pretty big (ten x 10 ft. by 10 ft. panels).

> Use common sense when determining a character’s success at damaging an object. Can a fighter cut through a section of a **stone wall** with a sword? No, the sword is likely to break before the wall does.

> You might decide that some damage types are more effective against a particular object or substance than others. [...] bludgeoning damage works well for smashing things but not for cutting through rope or leather. [...] A pick can chip away **stone** but can’t effectively cut down a tree. As always, use your best judgment.

I know 'use your best judgment' is not the takeaway you're looking for here 
but I'd apply these directions to give stone resistance against piercing and slashing damage but not bludgeoning. As you quoted 'objects are immune to poison and psychic damage' but I'd also give stone immunity to necrotic damage and resistance to things like fire  and acid damage. How you apply your judgement is obviously up to you - so I won't list every damage type here.

2. **The guidelines on HP don't tally that well with the spell description:**

A stone wall is normally considered Resilient and (at least) and each panel (at 10 ft by 10 ft) is large in size so would heave atleast 27 or 5d10 hp. The 30 hp per inch of thickness quoted in the spell description, seems at first glance to be within this range but the spell actually allows for 180 hp per panel, when you take the full thickness of a six inch wall into account.

3. **You can draw on damage thresholds from published modules**

The DMG doesn't provide explicit guidelines on appropriate damage thresholds. However, other published supplements do provide damage thresholds can be refferred to as a point of comparison:

- The hulls of larger boats in Ghosts of Saltmarsh (and now available via the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/vehicles)) have damage thresholds of between 10-20
- A submarine in Waterdeep: Dragon Heist has a damage threshold of 15, while it gives steel doors a threshold of 10
- Infernal machines and chains in Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus all have a threshold of 10.
- In Tomb of Annihilation there's a Crystal Window with a damage threshold of 15 and more chains with a threshold of 10.

**With all of the above in mind, a damage threshold of 15-20 feels appropriate for stone**.

As well as concerns of game balance and verisimilitude, when setting the damage threshold you might also want to consider exactly how difficult you want destroying the stone to be for your players, based on the current level. At low levels a threshold of 10 might be sufficient to impress upon your players the difficulty of destroying a wall, without completely removing the possibility of them doing so.

Comment: Please note that the spell [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone), which OP explicitly mentions as his primary concern, already provides numbers for the AC and hit points. The spell doesn't say anything about resistances, however, which I believe is what OP is confused by - if you don't extrapolate any additional properties beyond those listed in the spell, the wall would be susceptible to poison, for instance.

Comment: This question may have been inspired by the spell but the actual question is about official sources for the properties of stone that can be found outside of the spell description.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr: the official rule is that a stone wall such as the one created by [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) is immune to poison and psychic damage; everything beyond that can be summarized as "apply common sense".

---

#### There are no explicit rules for the properties of stone.

This is in line with the general concept of D&D 5th edition - there aren't rules for everything, and instead, many things are left up to the DM. This is reflected in the DMG section on objects (DMG, p. 246, emphasis mine):

> When characters need to saw through ropes, shatter a window, or smash a vampire's coffin, the only hard and fast rule is this: given enough time and the right tools, characters can destroy any destructible object. **Use common sense** when determining a character's success at damaging an object. Can a fighter cut through a section of a stone wall with a sword? No, the sword is likely to break before the wall does.
>
> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, **not a building** or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

This explicitly tells the DM to use common sense. The section on objects also mentions "stone" as an example for an object, but I'm fairly certain that this refers to something like a pebble or small boulder. Buildings are explicitly excluded, but seeing how the spell [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) lists the wall as "an object made of stone", I think we can safely assume that it counts as an object.

Considering the size of the wall, the wall would fall into the category of "Huge and Gargantuan Objects", meaning that it's hit points should be divided into sections - but the spell already does that for us. The same DMG section also states that "normal weapons are of little use against many Huge or Gargantuan objects", meaning that attacking the wall with your whip wouldn't do anything. I believe this is already covered by the common sense rule, though.

> ***Huge and Gargantuan Objects.*** Normal weapons are of little use against many Huge and Gargantuan objects, such as a colossal statue, towering column of stone, or massive boulder. That said, one torch can burn a Huge tapestry, and an earthquake spell can reduce a colossus to rubble. You can track a Huge or Gargantuan object's hit points if you like, or you can simply decide how long the object can withstand whatever weapon or force is acting against it. If you track hit points for the object, divide it into Large or smaller sections, and track each section's hit points separately. Destroying one of those sections could ruin the entire object. For example, a Gargantuan statue of a human might topple over when one of its Large legs is reduced to 0 hit points.

The section "Objects and Damage Types" tells us that objects are immune to psychic and poison damage, regardless of the material. Therefore, [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) is immune to those damage types as well.
Simultaneously, it states that "you might decide that some damage types are more effective against a particular object or substance than others" - yet another thing in line with the common sense rule.
For example, if a little gnome pokes the wall with a dagger or punches it, nothing's gonna happen (even though the latter would do bludgeoning damage) -> DM's discretion.
If a giant smacks the wall with his 10-foot giant greatsword, though, that's gonna do some damage, even though the sword would normally deal slashing damage. One could count the sword as an improvised weapon in this example, dealing bludgeoning damage simply due to its weight and impact.

The DMG also states that "Big objects such as castle walls" often have a damage threshold. No guidance is given on the value of this threshold, however.
In order not to screw up the balancing, I suggest not setting a threshold either; a wall can also be logically chipped away HP by HP as well. I don't believe a threshold is intended by the designers for [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone).

---

#### That being said: what are similar examples in the rules?

The spell [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) provides guidance on the AC and hit points of the wall - namely, AC 15 and 30 hit points per inch of thickness, counted separately for each panel of the wall.

This is in line with the spell [Mighty Fortress](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mighty-fortress) (XGtE, p. 161/162), which states:

> The walls, turrets, and keep are all made of stone that can be damaged. Each 10—foot—by-10-foot section of stone has AC 15 and 30 hit points per inch of thickness. It is immune to poison and psychic damage. Reducing a section of stone to 0 hit points destroys it and might cause connected sections to buckle and collapse at the DM’s discretion.

I think that seeing how both spells use the same AC and hit points, we can consider these stats to be fixed for these kinds of walls - the rules are "set in stone", so-to-speak.

In addition to the AC and HP rules, Mighty Fortress also states that the wall is immune to poison and psychic damage. This, too, is in line with the DMG rules on huge or gargantuan objects. This proves that my previous interpretation of applying these rules to [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) as well is likely correct. Similarly, *Mighty Fortress* also doesn't give any rules on a damage threshold either, despite explicitly including the DMG rules that were omitted for [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone).